# Get values from Tbody

Tags: javascript, html

I have `tbody` that looks like below :

```
<tbody class="yui-dt-data">
   <tr data-record-id="QB.D.FT1505UD.01.IP" class="rec-QB.D.FT1505UD.01.IP">
      <td class="yui-dt-col-market" data-column-id="market">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 300px;"><a class="tableIcon dealClosed" igtitle="Status: Market Closed#Action: No Action Available">FTSE to be above 6300.36 at 3:10pm</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-lightbulb" data-column-id="lightbulb">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 18px;"><a class="signal-status" href="#">&nbsp;</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-superNews" data-column-id="superNews">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 18px;"><a class="superNewsIcon off" igtitle="Reuters Info" href="#">&nbsp;</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-news" data-column-id="news">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 18px;"><a class="newsIcon off" href="#">&nbsp;</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-chart" data-column-id="chart">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 18px;"><a class="basicChartIcon on" href="#" igtitle="Chart">&nbsp;</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-menu" data-column-id="menu">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 18px;"><a class="optionsBtn" href="#" igtitle="Click for more options">&nbsp;</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-displayPeriod" data-column-id="displayPeriod">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" igtitle="" style="width: 80px;">06-JUN-16</div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-sell" data-column-id="sell">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 60px;">
            <div igtitle="Status: Market Open#Action: Place new Deal" class="dealOpen price">0.0</div>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-buy" data-column-id="buy">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 60px;">
            <div igtitle="Status: Market Open#Action: Place new Deal" class="dealOpen price">2.0</div>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-netChange" data-column-id="netChange">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner red" style="width: 69px;">-0.6</div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-percentageChange" data-column-id="percentageChange">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner blue" style="width: 68px;">6294.7</div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-updateTime" data-column-id="updateTime">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 75px;"><span>15:08:51</span></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-high" data-column-id="high">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 60px;"><span>100.0</span></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-low" data-column-id="low">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 60px;"><span>0.0</span></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-_extra" data-column-id="_extra">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 4000px;">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-record-id="QB.D.FT1505UD.02.IP" class="rec-QB.D.FT1505UD.02.IP">
      <td class="yui-dt-col-market" data-column-id="market">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner"><a class="tableIcon dealClosed" igtitle="Status: Market Closed#Action: No Action Available">FTSE to be above 6295.36 at 3:10pm</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-lightbulb" data-column-id="lightbulb">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner"><a class="signal-status" href="#">&nbsp;</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-superNews" data-column-id="superNews">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner"><a class="superNewsIcon off" igtitle="Reuters Info" href="#">&nbsp;</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-news" data-column-id="news">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner"><a class="newsIcon off" href="#">&nbsp;</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-chart" data-column-id="chart">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner"><a class="basicChartIcon on" href="#" igtitle="Chart">&nbsp;</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-menu" data-column-id="menu">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner"><a class="optionsBtn" href="#" igtitle="Click for more options">&nbsp;</a></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-displayPeriod" data-column-id="displayPeriod">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" igtitle="">06-JUN-16</div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-sell" data-column-id="sell">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner">
            <div igtitle="Status: Market Closed#Action: No Action Available" class="dealClosed price priceFlashDown">15.6</div>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-buy" data-column-id="buy">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner">
            <div igtitle="Status: Market Closed#Action: No Action Available" class="dealClosed price priceFlashDown">23.4</div>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-netChange" data-column-id="netChange">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner red">-0.6</div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-percentageChange" data-column-id="percentageChange">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner blue">6294.7</div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-updateTime" data-column-id="updateTime">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner"><span>15:09:42</span></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-high" data-column-id="high">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner"><span>100.0</span></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-low" data-column-id="low">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner"><span>0.0</span></div>
      </td>
      <td class="yui-dt-col-_extra" data-column-id="_extra">
         <div class="ig-table-cell-inner yui-dt-liner" style="width: 4000px;">&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

And I want get two positions:

1. `market` name from `<td class="yui-dt-col-market" data-column-id="market">`
2. `sell` value from `<td class="yui-dt-col-sell" data-column-id="sell">`

But I have no idea how get it from `tbody`.

There are two `tr` obejcts, I think that it should be loaded to array.

Please NOT jQuery solutions.

**Any idea?**

Comment: Is jQuery an option? You could just do `$('[data-column-id=market]').text()` and `$('[data-column-id=sell]').text()`.

Comment: Please in basic `JavaScript`. I try something like this `var tBody = divElement.querySelector('yui-dt-data');` but it does not work

Comment: jQuery will do this in literally 2 lines of code as @dyagmin suggested, no reason to do this with plain JS.

Comment: I need get this values to object, cause I redirect it to other functions. Like `var sellValue = tBody.get....`. How to get it ? I think about any loops because in this `tbody` are many objects and I want catch them all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this : 
1) Get all rows from tbody
2) Get all 'td' from each row

```
var rows =document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows;
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
var td = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[i];
console.log(td)
}
```

Than do whatever you want to do with this td object.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vinni0803/63y7wtrw/)

Comment: Yes I need something like this but It does not work :/

Comment: Its working if <tbody> is contained with in <table></table>.

Comment: Ok but it get only lines, I need `<td class="yui-dt-col-market">` and get only name `FTSE to be above 6298.36 at 4:10pm`and with values from `...yuu-dt-col-buy` like value `2.0` named `dealPrice`. NOT full line <td...>

Comment: I see example which You added but there is full lines of info, I need only `MARKET` and `SELL` value.

Comment: I have updated the example , you change it a/c to your needs. http://jsfiddle.net/vinni0803/63y7wtrw/

Comment: Vinni in this code which You add is exactly the same, getting full lines - not selected fields (market name, sell, buy)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are on the right lines with querySelector, you just need to get the syntax correct by using `[data-column-id="market"]` to specify an element has an attribute with a certain value:

```
var data = [];

// loop through all rows
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr');

rows.forEach(function(row) {
  var obj = {};

  // get the td element with attribute data-column-id="market"
  var marketElement = row.querySelector('td[data-column-id="market"]');
  if(marketElement !== null) {
    // exists - set the object property
    // if you need to parse this to extract "FTSE", that is a separate task
    obj.market = marketElement.innerText.trim();
  }

  // get the td element with attribute data-column-id="sell"
  var sellElement = row.querySelector('td[data-column-id="sell"]');
  if(sellElement !== null) {
    // exists - set the object property
    obj.sell = sellElement.innerText.trim();
  }

  // add object to the result array
  data.push(obj);
});
```

You can make it a little "simpler" by assuming that values will definitely exist in a row, but this could lead to undefined value errors if you aren't careful:

```
var data = [];
document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr').forEach(function(row) {
  data.push({
    market: row.querySelector('td[data-column-id="market"]').innerText.trim(),
    sell: row.querySelector('td[data-column-id="sell"]').innerText.trim(),
  });
});
```

Comment: It is so complicated... There is no other easiest way to get this values ?

Comment: It's not complicated, just a little long-winded, have updated with a shorter, but potentially more risky version. Even using jquery would make it much cleaner.

Comment: Please look at vinni comment and I want get it like this but need for(tbody elements) and values `market` and `sell`. For `market` ex: `FTSE to be above 6298.36 at 4:10pm and for `sell` ex: `2.0`

Comment: yes that is exactly what you have. You mean you have multiple `tbody` elements? That doesn't match what you wrote in the question, but you can use the same idea to extend this yourself to loop through the `tbody`s and then their `tr`s

Comment: Rhumborl I mean that in `tbody` I have many elements (many markets which contains data sell or buy price) and I want load this informations (markets name, sell, buy) for each element (each market)